# Creating a listener in TIBCO Rendezvous

Tags: tibco

I'm trying to create a listener in tibco rendezvous. I want to listen in on a particular subject. I'm aware that its supposed to look something like this:

```
TibrvListener(
TibrvQueue queue,
TibrvMsgCallback callback,
TibrvTransport transport,
java.lang.String subject,
java.lang.Object closure)
throws TibrvException
```

I have this code. However, I don't know a couple of things. How do I create a `TibrvMsgCallback` object? How do I pass in the transport? I have a publisher that sends the message as a seperate program. Do I recreate an identical transport in my subscribe program?

```
queue = new TibrvQueue();
dispatcher = new TibrvDispatcher(queue);
queue.setName(key);
this.listener = new TibrvListener(queue, null, null, subject, null);
TibrvTransport message = this.listener.getTransport();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first open the Tibrv
Tibrv.open(Tibrv.IMPL_NATIVE);

Create transport
TibrvTransport transport = new TibrvRvdTransport(service, network, daemon);

Create Listener
new TibrvListener(Tibrv.defaultQueue(), this, transport, subject, null);

If your listener is "this", your class needs to implement TibrvMsgCallback

Messages can be processed on arrival in the onMsg(TibrvListener listener, TibrvMsg msg) method.

Comment: thank you very very much! that was very helpful! the only thing i still don't understand is how i create the TibrvMsgCallback

Comment: You don't create the TibrvMsgCallback. The class where you would like to process the tibrv msgs, needs to implement that interface so that your class can implement the onMsg() method. Does your Tibco installation have examples such as in TIBRV\src\examples\java?

Comment: ah i see so i add a implements and then the onMsg method.  nope i have no examples at all so i'm trying to write a program basically in the dark :(

Comment: is there somewhere that i can get these examples?

Comment: I believe they should be present with the Tibco installation.